# Kentico navigation webparts and multi-language

Tags: kentico

Am i correct in assuming that i need a nav webpart for each language with the correct corresponding culture code set?

I have on cms:CMSListMenu in my .Master page, and i'm going to be starting the french version of the site.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `.master` pages vs. portal engine pages?

Comment: We started off as pure portal, but next phase is remote data integration, so the director of tech wanted local .aspx pages. So, here i am.

Comment: You might look into creating webparts and using settings for that vs. aspx pages.  They offer reuse and a lot more flexibility in the CMS than an aspx page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is NOT correct.  Kentico is made to use a single template and/or webpart for multiple languages.  You do have the opportunity to use different templates per language but unless you need it for something very specific, it's not needed.

The webparts are smart enough to use the current language which has been selected/set on the website.  There are some additional configuration options you can set like mixing the default culture with the current culture.  What this means is if you are viewing the site in French and have a page in English but not French, it will display the English version and in place of the missing French version.

I'd suggest starting out with the [Kentico localization documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K8/Setting+up+multilingual+websites) if you haven't already.

Comment: Thanks Brenden, i went down this rabbit hole with customizing the breadcrumb webpart to have a home link.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no need to customize the control @MarkHandy because you can simply place some static HTML before and after in the webpart without any issue to get your "home" link.  If you find yourself customizing webparts and their code for something simple like that, in most cases it can be done with a different approach in Kentico vs. modifying code.  I'd highly suggest against modifying the OOTB controls/code.

Comment: This is something that may need a refactor. I've learned a lot about different approaches within Kentico.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I can't agree with you assumption. You can specify culture for you control, so it will always use that culture, otherwise it should be using current culture.

Comment: Ok, so if i specify the culture, i would need to duplicate the webpart, which i don't want to do.

Thanks!